# Запрос на выборку данных mysql, sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM (

     SELECT t.name as tags, ... FROM backlink b
     INNER JOIN website w ON b.website=w.id
     LEFT JOIN tag_backlink tb ON b.id=tb.backlink
     LEFT JOIN tag t ON tb.tag=t.id
     WHERE ...
     UNION
     SELECT t.name as tags, ... FROM tag t 
     INNER JOIN tag_backlink tb ON tb.tag=t.id
     INNER JOIN backlink b ON b.id=tb.backlink
     INNER JOIN website w ON b.website=w.id
     WHERE ...`

) b ORDER BY...
```

Он выдает такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он выдает три результата для одного tb.tag. Мне нужно получить для одного tb.tag один результат, но с тремя t.name as tags.
Вот такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это возможно? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу только один способ: `GROUP_CONCAT(t.name)` и `GROUP BY(tb.tag)`.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь. Этот способ дал результат, но частично. Группирование происходит, но те строки у которых нет связи с t.name, все также объединяются в одну, а нужно чтобы они в таком случае оставались без объединения. Знаете как с этим бороться? Пробовал, но пока безуспешно

Comment: Поскольку Вы дали запрос без подробностей, я лишь привел Вам пример, исходя из него. Группируйте по уникальному ID записей в таблице tag, это надёжнее и правильнее.

Comment: Да, то что надо. Спасибо большое. Не подумал об этом... Подробностями не хотел перегружать, хотя иногда они нужны...